# Proof of the linear approximation

Tags: calculus

For a function f(x) defined near the origin I'm trying to show the following:

f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + o(x)

Say we have:   p(x) = a + bx , the linear approximation of f(x) near the origin.

What I got so far:

Since p(x) is the linear approx., then

f(x) - p(x) = o(x) ....... (1)

0 = f(0) - p(0) = f(0) - a

So I got f(0) = a. Now i'm trying to find f'(0) using the definition of a derivative, so I'm looking for this expression:

lim   ((f(x) - f(0) / x) - b) as x goes to 0 , from here I would get that f'(0) = b, which leads me to what I'm looking for :

f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + o(x)

What I intend to do is divide both sides of (1) over x and take the limit, but is it correct saying that the limit of o(x)/x as x goes to 0 is 0? Or is there any other method to do so?

Comment: Yes! The limit of $o(x)/x$ does go to $0$ as $x \to 0$. This is why we care about $o(x)$ to begin with.

Comment: Would you mind explaining me why? I'm having some difficulties understanding the little o notation. If x goes to 0, wouldn't I have something like 0/0? Do you apply L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the problem. The limit of $o(x)/x$ goes to $0$ as $x \to 0$ is a matter of definition. What you want to show is the formula $f(x) = f(0) + xf'(0) + o(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have a function $f(x)$ that is defined and differentiable near the origin, so that a linear approximation exists. The linear approximation is, by definition, $f(0) + xf'(0)$, and we will write $a = f(0)$ and $b = f'(0)$. What we want to show is that

$$f(x) - a - bx = o(x)$$

In other words, that

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - a - bx}{x} \to 0$$

However, we can rewrite this

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} - f'(0)$$

Can you see why this should go to $0$?